# How to add new { @class = "form-control } to MVC View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How to add form control to this statement. Please help a beginner out :-(

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Datum, 
    new { placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.Datum, ViewData).Watermark }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

You have to add it on the 2nd parameter which is an anonymous object like this;

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Something, new { @class="test", @otherProperties =""})
```

So for your code it's;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Datum, new { @class="form-control", @placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.Datum, ViewData).Watermark })
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jerdine for your post! Works as it should. I Apologize for the level of question asked but im new to this and I truly didn't manage to get it to work.

Comment: @Ariador1987 if this helped, can you please mark as the answer?

Comment: Very new to his, didn't know it was possible literally, was just focused on my problem. Did look around and did so. Thank you for notifying me that this is an option (and standard etiquette. Thanks.